# Firebase: limited and secure service access from Pyrebase?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

When using Firebase's server API, you can provide additional `databaseAuthVariableOverride` section to limit access of the service account, as described [in the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/server/start#authenticate-with-limited-privileges). I wanted to use [Pyrebase](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase), as it's in python and supports using service accounts. However, if I log in using a service account there, it has full access to the database -- the validation rules before write are not checked (while I do want them to be checked).

So, there are two parts to this question:

1. Is it possible to add support for `databaseAuthVariableOverride` into Pyrebase at all? I see it uses Firebase REST API, and I don't know if that supports it, and where should I send that variable.
2. I can work around this issue by not using the service account, but a normal email/password account set to a particular email, and add root read/write rules checking `auth.email === '<my-email>` and/or `auth.uid === '<my-account-uid>'`. Question here is: is this equally secure as using a service account with limited access (as linked on the top)?

Comment: You'll probably get better response to #1 if you post the feature request on the Pyrebase repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in the security rules between an auth.uid that you've set using [Authenticate with limited privileges](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/server/start#authenticate-with-limited-privileges) or one that is determined by [signing in with email&password](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth).