# Firebase Database security rules works in simulator, not in the java code

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I want to block addition of data with timestamps older than existing ones. Sample database:

```
{
  "latest" : {
    "517" : {
      "PARAM1" : {
        "timestamp" : 11492,
        "value" : 6593
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Firebase security rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",

    "latest": {
        "$id": {
            "$param": {
                "timestamp": { ".validate": "newData.val() >= data.val()" }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, interesting part. When I check adding different data from the simulator - it works as expected. Smaler timestamps are rejected, higher are added. But it doesn't make any impact on adding THE SAME data from the Java code.

Sample data which should be rejected:

```
/latest/517
{
  "PARAM1" : {
    "timestamp" : -5,
    "value" : 643
  }
}
```

I use `com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:4.0.3` with pure Java as described in [Admin Database API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start) section.

POJO:

```
public class TimeValue {

    public long timestamp;
    public double value;

    public TimeValue(long timestamp, double value) {
        super();
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

Inserting:

```
Map<String, TimeValue> timeValue = new HashMap<String, TimeValue>();
timeValue.put("PARAM1", new TimeValue(-5L, 643));

final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference idRef = database.getReference("latest/517");
idRef.setValue(timeValue);
```

Why it works that way? It doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use firebase as admin, or as a service account, the validation rules are not checked -- because, well, you're an admin :)

If you just want normal access to the database, you can just sign in as a regular account.

If you want to have admin privileges, but still want the validation rules checked, you just need to use a "special" account that will always satisfy the read/write rules. I stumbled upon this too some time ago, there are two basic ways to do it, explained in my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39098190/firebase-limited-and-secure-service-access-from-pyrebase) (apparently equally safe, as this was my question back then):

1. Use [databaseAuthVariableOverride](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/server/start#authenticate-with-limited-privileges) to set some special auth property, which is checked in root `.read`/`.write` rules, and is true *only* for the service account.
2. Create a special account (even a plain email/password), and hardcode its uid, email or other property in the same rules (root's `.read`/`.write`).

Comment: Thank you! I spent too much time on this ;-).